# Is there a function for a self start model to estimate the parameter of a Gaussian model in R?

Tags: python, r, gaussian

I need to estimate the parameters of a Gaussian model. I like to use self start to select the parameters. I already did something like this using a logistic model with a different dataset. I would like to know if there is a similar function of SSlogis for gaussian

```
x <- runif(20)
y <- rexp(20)
a <- data.frame(x,y)

log_model <- nls(y~SSlogis(x, phi1, phi2, phi3), data = a)
```

What I want is to do a similar approach but using a gaussian model. I didn't find a function similar to SSlogis for a gaussian distribution. The R documentation said that there is an `SSgauss` function but I didn't find it https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xcms/versions/1.48.0/topics/SSgauss
I saw something similar to what I want in a python3 code.

```
def gaussian_f(x,a,b,c):
   y = a * np.exp(-0.5 * ((x-b)/c)**2)
   return y
##optimize from scipy
gaussian_m, cov = optimize.curve_fit(gaussian_f, x=np.arrange(len(a["y"])), y=dtf["y"].values, maxfev=10000, p0=[1,np.mean(a["y"]) ,1]
```

Comment: what trouble did you have with finding `SSgauss`? You need `install.packages("BiocManager"); BiocManager::install("xcms"); library(xcms)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is open source and Bioconductor releases package [xcms](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/xcms.html) under

> License: GPL (>= 2)

so the source code for function `SSgauss` can be downloaded and used as long as the users follow the licensing terms.

Here is the source code for the function found in file `xcms/R/models.R`.

```
SSgauss <- selfStart(~ h*exp(-(x-mu)^2/(2*sigma^2)), function(mCall, data, LHS) {
  
  xy <- sortedXyData(mCall[["x"]], LHS, data)
  
  len <- dim(xy)[1]
  xyarea <- sum((xy[2:len,2]+xy[1:(len-1),2])*(xy[2:len,1]-xy[1:(len-1),1]))/2
  maxpos <- which.max(xy[,2])
  
  mu <- xy[maxpos,1]
  h <- xy[maxpos,2]
  sigma <- xyarea/(h*sqrt(2*pi))
  
  value <- c(mu, sigma, h)
  names(value) <- mCall[c("mu", "sigma", "h")]
  value
  
}, c("mu", "sigma", "h"))
```

Now fit a gaussian model to the data set in the question.

```
x <- runif(20)
y <- rexp(20)
a <- data.frame(x, y)

gauss_model <- nls(y ~ SSgauss(x, mu, sigma, h), data = a)
summary(gauss_model)
#
#Formula: y ~ SSgauss(x, mu, sigma, h)
#
#Parameters:
#      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#mu      0.5844     0.0989   5.909 1.72e-05 ***
#sigma   0.3540     0.1436   2.465  0.02463 *  
#h       1.2453     0.3364   3.702  0.00177 ** 
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 0.7832 on 17 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.897e-06
```